# Android AppWidget size

Tags: android, android-appwidget

i am creating a few appwidgets on android. I would also like to resuse the layouts of the appwidgets so i can make controls in my activities so it looks the same.

So that working fine the problem i have is the sizes I would like to get it the same size.

[Appwidget Image](http://img545.imageshack.us/i/homeu.png/)

[Activity Image](http://img576.imageshack.us/i/manifest.png/)

Here is the widget xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="72dp" android:initialLayout="@layout/sitewidget"
    android:minWidth="146dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="60000"
    android:configure="com.leaflabs.jaws_editor.SiteWidgetConfigure">
</appwidget-provider>
```

as you can see the appwidget size is not exacly the same size as the controls size.

The question is how do i get it the same. I specified in the control ctor the following to get it the same size but its not correct

```
Resources r = context.getResources();

float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                146, r.getDisplayMetrics());

float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                72, r.getDisplayMetrics());

setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the appwidget's root layout to a FrameLayout (just an example), and 
place your control in a LinearLayout as a child of it. Then specify your size to that LinearLayout.

The dimensions in the appwidget-provider dont apply to the exact size.